# PyPy3 won't install OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, pypy

I am writing a program that splits a video into frames and extract the text of every nth frame using opencv-python and pytesseract. I managed to get the code working, but the program was working rather slowly. I tried to use PyPy3 to improve performance but ran into an issue installing the opencv library for pypy.

This is the error code:

```
    Collecting opencv-python
      Using cached opencv-python-4.6.0.66.tar.gz (90.3 MB)
      Installing build dependencies: started
      Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
      Getting requirements to build wheel: started
      Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
      Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
    Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in /usr/local/Cellar/pypy3/7.3.9/libexec/site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.21.6)
    Building wheels for collected packages: opencv-python
      Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml): started
      Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
    Failed to build opencv-python
    
    DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
      × Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [9 lines of output]
          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "/private/var/folders/55/4bdtvdzn54n8npg5kfybcvq40000gp/T/pip-build-env-_2gw8fsy/overlay/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 613, in setup
              cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
            File "/private/var/folders/55/4bdtvdzn54n8npg5kfybcvq40000gp/T/pip-build-env-_2gw8fsy/overlay/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 141, in __init__
              self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
            File "/private/var/folders/55/4bdtvdzn54n8npg5kfybcvq40000gp/T/pip-build-env-_2gw8fsy/overlay/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 96, in get_cmake_version
              "Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is %s" % cmake_executable
          
          Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
          [end of output]
      
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python
    ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I feel like I tried everything. I successfully installed all other dependencies using

```
pypy3 -m pip install [package]
```

Yes, I already upgraded my pip, setuptools and wheels to the latest version.

Any other relevant information:

interpreter path: `/usr/local/bin/pypy3`

Python version: `PyPy 7.3.9 [Python 3.7.13]`

OS: MacOS

What I understand is that the error lies with building the wheels and I read something about building the package myself. I couldn't figure it out tho. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

I installed cmake using `brew install cmake`. Now when I try to install opencv-python, instead of raising an ERROR, the cmd gets stuck at
`Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml) ... |`

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that it may be linked to cmake, You can try to install it. -> https://cmake.org/install/

Comment: I did. Now cmd is stuck on building wheel as presented in the EDIT